# Custom form field for a model field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to use [USSocialSecurityNumberField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/localflavor/#django.contrib.localflavor.us.forms.USSocialSecurityNumberField) in a model. To be precise I'm ok with having CharField in the model but I would like it to inject USSocialSecurityNumberField to modelforms based on that model.

Is there any way to override the default form field for a model field, other than [subclassing model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-model-fields/#specifying-the-form-field-for-a-model-field) ? I mean something like:

```
ssn = models.CharField(max_length=11, formfield=USSocialSecurityNumberField)
```

This would be the simplest solution for what is a one-time need.

PS. I'm also interested in other combinations of model fields and form fields, so subclassing is an annoying solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's exactly what you are looking for. If you are interested in validating the value of the formfield you may use validators:

```
def validate_USSocialSecurityNumberField(myNumber):
    # here goes the validation algorithm which will raise a ValidationError 
    # if the number is not in the correct format
    # and of course you will catch the exception
    # except ValueError:
    #     raise ValidationError(u'"%s" is not in the correct format!' % myNumber)
```

and your model may look like:

```
ssn = models.CharField(max_length=11, validators = [validate_USSocialSecurityNumberField])
```

Comment: Actually it looks like you can use USSocialSecurityNumberField.clean as a validator!

Answer (score 1):

Such argument exist neither for Field nor for ModelField. But subclassing should not be too difficult, I believe something along the lines of this should work:

```
class MyModelField(models.Field):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['form_class'] = forms.USSocialSecurityNumberField
        return super(MyModelField, self).formfield(**kwargs)
```

Comment: This of course works but @unichiduci's answer pointed me in a promising direction so I'm accepting his answer. Thanks anyway!